# How to keep strings together in list

Tags: python, html

I am trying to create a list then output it as a table with html but my list always comes out like this:

```
 <TR>
  <TD>N</TD>
  <TD>o</TD>
  <TD>l</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE> (shortened version)
```

I've tried using append, extend, str format but nothing so far. Here is some code:

```
import HTML
table = []
string = str(row[2]+" ["+row[25]+"]")
table.append(string)
htmlcode = HTML.table(table)
print htmlcode
```

Comment: What is this `HTML.table(table)` function? That's producing your final output, but we have no knowledge of what this class/function is or does.

Comment: @daveruinseverything https://www.decalage.info/python/html

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html) 
you should use this function like this :

```
>>> t = HTML.table(border='1')
>>> for i in range(2):
>>>   r = t.tr
>>>   r.td('column 1')
>>>   r.td('column 2')
>>> print t
<table border="1">
<tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is t.tr? saying 'str' object has no attribute 'tr' even though i've treated it as a table.

Comment: it represent <tr> tag, are you sure import library first ?

Comment: I am using the library that I linked in my original post here: decalage.info/python/html